# Breaking polygons into paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

Is there anyway to break up a polygon into paths? Actually what I want to do is to change the colour and dash of certain sides of the polygon, but that seems like the straight forward way. I can't seem to make this work. I know I could draw the polygon from scratch but that seems tedious given that there exists a polygon drawing tool...

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed, it does require a few steps:

1. Select the polygon
2. Execute the menu command `Paths->Object to path`
3. Select the Node tool (F2)
4. Select the polygon's nodes at the vertices with Shift + click
5. Click on the "Break path at selected nodes" button [image]
6. execute the menu command `Path->break Apart` (ctrl + shift + k)

There you are, just unselect the objects, and you can now select the 
lines individually. You probably will want to make use of `Objects->group` to stick
the lines together in the polygon after you are done.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, that actually worked and I feel really stupid knowing the solution was so simple. Anyway, thanks a ton!